# How to retrieve current object from collections using DataBinder.Eval?

Tags: asp.net, collections

I am retrieving Objects from a collection and assigned objects and objects within objects to web user control from hosting web page.

```
<uc1:bookmarksList   runat ="server"   Link =<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OLinks")%>
```

where Olinks is the objects within current objects list in collections(e.g User is current object in collection) my question how to  retrieve current object from collections in syntax

DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem..

Answer (score 1):

**Eval** or **Bind** methods already gets the current object of a collection. You're probably using Eval function in a databound control. Your databound control loops your collection and each loop it gets the current item of the collection. You should eval a property of your control in your collection. In your example it looks like you're binding the object itself.